# Is it possible to set useQuery result data type with multiple types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-query

I use useQuery from react-query and axios to fetch data, and I want it to return data with specific data types, which are `Task[]` and `PaginationType`. But the `query.data` type seems like recognized as an arbitrary object or nullable (can be undefined). This lead to misinterpreted autocompletion. any one can help me to refactor the code? is it possible to do this? if it is not, may I have advice on how to separate the concern into different codes?

totalPages property is not recognized in the component
[image]

hasMore property is not recognized in custom hook react-query
[image]

Task

```
export type BaseEntity = {
    id: string;
    createdAt: number;
    updatedAt: number;
};

export type Task = {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  labels : Array<Label>
} & BaseEntity;
```

PaginationType

```
export type PaginationType = {
    hasMore : boolean;
    items : Task[];
    total : number;
    perPage : number;
    currentPage : number;
    totalPages : number;
    lastPage : number;
    nextPageUrl : string;
    prevPageUrl : string;
    onFirstPage : boolean;
    onLastPage : boolean; 
    path : string;
    links : [];
}
```

```
export type SearchTasksDTO = {
  search: string;
  labels: Option[] | number[]
  assignees: Option[] | number[]
} & PaginationProps;

export const getTasks = (params? : SearchTasksDTO):  (Promise<Task[] | PaginationType>) => {
  if(params){ 
    return axios.get('/tasks',{ params : params }).then(res => {
      if(params.paginate){
        return res.data as PaginationType
      } else return res.data as Task[]
    });
  }
  return axios.get('/tasks').then(res => res.data);
};

type QueryFnType = typeof getTasks;

type UseTasksOptions = {
  paginate? : boolean
  params? : SearchTasksDTO;
  config?: QueryConfig<QueryFnType>;
};

type PaginationProps = {
  paginate? : boolean;
  limit? : number;
}

export const useTasks = ({ config = {}, params }: UseTasksOptions) => {
  const queryKey : QueryKey = params ? ['tasks', params] : ['tasks'];

  const query = useQuery<ExtractFnReturnType<QueryFnType>>({
    ...config,
    queryKey: queryKey,
    queryFn: ()=> getTasks(params),
  });

  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!query.isPreviousData && query.data?.hasMore) {
      query.refetch();
    }
  }, [query.data, query.isPreviousData, params]);
  
  return query;
};
```

This code can be found in my public github repository. In case you want to know more about the whole codebase. Here's the link : https://github.com/galih56/manpro-v2

Comment: I see the problem, useQuery return isLoading too. you need to make sure data exist before rendering the Pagination component. data.totalPages && <Pagination  .../>

Comment: @PrinceSodhi i already done that, but it can't recognize the data type because i set my http function return data type with ```Promise<Task[]> | Promise<PaginationType>```. So the app can't understand what the function will return Task[] or PaginationType

Comment: I cloned ur repo, but I don’t see the problem. in which is the problem?

Comment: @PrinceSodhi I guess it's some TS extension or editor issue. Do you see any red underscore in the TaskList component as shown in the image above?

Comment: I don't see how TS is wrong here, you have `Task[] | PaginationType` and `totalPages` simply doesn't exist on `Task[]`. Could you explain what you think should happen?

Comment: I updated my http client function to return this ``` PaginationType<Task[]> | Task[]>```. 
My editor shows error message about some properties that are unknown to typescript. As example, you can see in my custom hook react-query, the hasMore property doesn't

Comment: doesn't recognized, there is red underscore under it.